# Get the minimum timestamp for ids larger than or equal to itself

Tags: mysql

I have a user table, the important columns are these.

```
id | logintime
---+-----------
1  | 2004-01-10
2  | 2006-02-10
3  | 2005-03-12
4  | 2006-10-23
```

I want to create a column that approximates time the user registered. To do this I want to take the lowest logintime on id and every id larger than itself. the logintime is the last time the id has logged into the site.

While it is not perfect, it gives a "latest possible date" for the registertime. Since id is autoincrement we know that the person with id 2 has registered before the person with id 3, so we approximate the registertime for id 2 with the logintime for id 3.

The result would be

```
id | logintime  | Registertime
---+------------+-------------
1  | 2004-01-10 | 2004-01-10
2  | 2006-02-10 | 2005-03-12
3  | 2005-03-12 | 2005-03-12
4  | 2006-10-23 | 2006-10-23
```

Can I do this with one query? I think I can achieve it with a t-cursor, but that seems a bit too fancy for this, simple, task.

**Edit**: Clarified the question.

Comment: I don't understand how the result set satisfies the criteria

Comment: @Strawberry clarified the question, hopefully you understand it better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it with a sub-query in the select

```
SELECT a.id, a.logintime,
       (SELECT MIN(logintime) 
        FROM table b
        WHERE b.id >= a.id) Registertime
FROM table a
```

With a join it will look like:

```
SELECT a.id, a.logintime, MIN(b.logintime) Registertime
FROM table a INNER JOIN table b on b.id >= a.id
GROUP BY a.id, a.logintime
```

I'm not sure which one is better in terms of performance though.

Comment: Works perfectly. It will be a one time query, so performance is not a big issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this patter `Select a.MIN(timespamp) from <yourtable>as A,<yourtable>as b where a.id<=b.id;`

hope this works

Comment: This uses old style joins, which are very much discouraged. There are more syntax errors in there, and even corrected for everything, the code does not return what I need.